# Bug when storing sessions in the database (Yii 1)

Tags: php, mysql, session, yii

I have project on yii 1 and when i use DB for saving sessions i received bug. For each query to the site in the database creates a new entry. I don't know why.
Therefore I can not get a variable from the session, becouse after refrtsh page i have a new entry in db.
What i am doing wrong?
Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `wo_yiisession` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`expire` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`data` TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `expire_idx` (`expire`)
```

)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB

session component setings:

```
'session' => array(
        'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
        'connectionID' => 'db',
        'sessionTableName' => 'wo_yiisession',
        'timeout' => 3600 * 24 * 30,
        'autoStart' => 'false',
        'cookieMode' => 'only',
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your ID field is wrong type. Proposed table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE YiiSession
(
    id CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
    expire INTEGER,
    data BLOB
)
```

See [CDbHttpSession](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbHttpSession)